# HTML5 CSS3 Floating Input Text Over Cell Containing Image

Tags: html, css

Looking for a quick easy way to Add Text on top of a pic as a user fills in fields on a form.

I am trying to create an order form for a Brick Design Project I am running and this is driving me crazy.

I am trying to keep it simple as I am just trying to learn styling and coding through CSS3 and HTML5.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <br />&nbsp;
        <br /> &nbsp;
        <br /> &nbsp;
        <br />
        <label for="Line1">Line1:</label>
        <input id="Line1" name="Line1" value="" maxlength="18">
        <br />&nbsp;
        <br />
        <label for="Line2">Line2:</label>
        <input id="Line2" name="Line2" value="" maxlength="18">
        <br />&nbsp;
        <br />
        <label for="Line3">Line3:</label>
        <input id="Line3" name="Line3" value="" maxlength="18">
        <br />&nbsp;
        <br />
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><img src="paver.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" border="2" alt="" /> [Line1]
        </br>[Line2]</br>[Line3]</br>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset Values">
        <br />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Quick View">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

In properly used HTML5 and CSS3, the main thing is to separate presentation from content.

-> Content: goes into the HTML.

So you have a from, labels, input fields, some buttons

You do not have a table! (when looking at content)]

-> layout (presentation) goes into the CSS

Here you would have sizes, positionining, colors, background images, etc.

Now your image you want behind your form: it's hard to tell up front this has to be presentation (I'd guess in 99% of cases it would be), but it could be argued otherwise in more rare cases.

Once you have this separated, how it looks is mere CSS, and in CSS putting things over one another or using background images etc. is all pretty much a piece of cake.

So what do you want to end up with?

HTML:

- a form!
- a fieldset (optional)
- the input fields (they need atype AFAIK)

Try to avoid any and all that's just there for how it looks.

CSS:
Everything needed to make it look like what you seek to have
(but you currently have nothing, so it's kinda hard to nudge you in the right direction)

I'd suggest a good tutorial.

Ref: (these contain a lot more detail and examples)

- https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Styling_HTML_forms

Comment: Sorry, I didnt add my CSS, was trying to do an overlay of sorts, but wondering if there is any way to capture a variable without javascript.

Comment: Without javascript: your form, once completed gets sent to the server as per the instructions in the '<form>' tag. Javascript can be used to do something of your choice within the page based on various user actions (or even inactions). It's important to know where things run: server vs. browser. Javascript would be running in the browser and hence unless the scripts starts to communicate with the server, the server cannot react to things only the client knows something about.